# Background Image Pushed to the Right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've set a background image to my app however when displaying in web browsers it gets pushed to the right like this:

[image]

When I add `margin-left: -213px;` the image is corrected however when displaying in a mobile browser it gets messed up due to the margin property.

CSS File:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.background {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -213px;
  background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Generated HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>App</title>
    <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application-4f1b4b41b9ae7b2172e04bc0efdd0472.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-73022516521c5ed853bbbb1f8630f920.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="icons">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-fw"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i></a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="navbar-link" href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
    <div class="container">
<div class="background">
</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why this is happening? Can I add the margin-left property just to web browsers?

Comment: It's hard to find the bug without seeing the code.

Comment: Could you provide us a demo-link ?

Comment: Show your full `<body>` code. It is looked like, that your background div is inside Bootstrap's container div. Also, why not to add background to body?

Comment: I've already tried too but I cant reproduce bootstrap features on jsfiddle

Comment: If I add background to body it will also get displayed on other pages which is not my objective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `container` div from this code. Everything inside container centered on the page, and this left margin is from this div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the <div class="container"> for some reason was in my application.html. After I removed it worked perfectly.

Comment: In fact my solution would be to add an `id` with background to `body`, and add this id to body tag on necessary pages through rails. It will be more DRY.

Answer (score 3):

Using the same code you provided, my solution would be to remove the rules:

```
 display: table;
 margin-left: -213px;
```

And, instead, add:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

To the **.background** class

Answer (score 2):

Use developer tools of the browser to inspect what is happening. For me it looks like there is some element on the left which is hidden/shown depending on the screen size (media queries)

Answer (score 2):

Try below Css :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
.background {

/*add your desired css it will show only on the screens which are above 960px
(you can change this value though..) For example:*/
margin-left:-213px;  /* negative value this much I personally don't recommend  */        

}
}
```

just check if this solves your issue ... :)